# Why do scattered waves vanish when the wavenumber of the incident wave is an eigenvalue of the interior Dirichlet problem. Where has the energy gone?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, acoustics, scattering, resonance

I normally work with numerical computations for wave scattering, but I am now trying to get a better understanding of the physical processes underlying the theory, in particular, what happens to the incoming energy which seems to disappear in certain special situations! The questions I ask are also applicable to the scattering of electromagnetic and elastic waves but I will ask about acoustic waves for simplicity.

Suppose we have an incident acoustic wave $u^{in}(x;k)$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $k$ is the wavenumber of that is incident on a sound-hard obstacle which is represented by a bounded domain $D$. This models the situation where the domain $D$ has an infinitely large acoustic impedance (mass density) so no waves can penetrate it. The governing equation for wave propagation is the Helmholtz equation
$$
\Delta u + k^2 u = 0, \quad \mathbb{R}^3\backslash\overline{D}.
$$
**Questions:**

1. There are certain wavenumbers $k$ for which we will have no scattered wave. These correspond to Dirichlet eigenvalues of the interior problem for the domain $D$. **What is going on here, how can it happen that we have no scattered waves? What happens to all the energy of the incident wave?**
2. Say we 'decrease' the acoustic impedance a bit so it is still massive but no longer infinitely large. Due to the extremely high impedance, we have an almost total reflection of waves, but there will be a small amount of transmission into $D$. This means we also need to transmit boundary conditions on (for the field and its normal derivative) on the boundary of $D$. However, yet again, in this case, there are particular wavenumbers $k$ for which we have no scattering. These are known as interior transmission eigenvalues. By lowering the impedance we have 'shifted' from Dirichlet eigenvalues to interior transmission eigenvalues. I imagine if we increased the acoustic impedance back up to infinity, these eigenvalues would move back towards the Dirichlet eigenvalues? **Now, in the case of these transmission eigenvalues, I again wonder, what has happened to the energy of the incident wave if no waves get scattered?** Does this situation have some connection to the phenomenon of resonance?
3. On the other hand, it is known that if an incident wave excites a penetrable object at resonance, there will an enhancement of the scattering. For example, if a gas bubble in water is excited by an incident wave at resonance, it will act as a monopole scatterer, that is, it will oscillate (collapse and expand) at its natural frequency and lead to a dramatic increase in scattering. But in question 2 we have seen that the interior transmission eigenvalues produce no scattered wave at all. **So are wavenumbers $k$ that correspond to resonance something other than the interior transmission eigenvalues?** Or are there different notions of resonance? In any case, what conditions are required for $k$ to imply resonant scattering enhancement?

Comment: Great question and my +1! It is actually quite a general question, so I have a few suggestions to make it easier for people that are not familiar with acoustic scattering (such as myself, I work on electromagnetic scattering) to respond: 1. You talk about lowering the acoustic impedance in your second point. It would be helpful if you could write down the Helmholtz equation for spatially dependent acoustic impedance. 2. Could you give a reference for where you got your information from? In particular the theorem about the interior Dirichlet solutions. 3. Is k a wave*vector*? Or a wavenumber?

Comment: Aren't solutions matching the eigenvalues of an initial boundary condition equivalent to saying that the oscillations are standing modes in this case?  That is, the eigenvalue solutions represent the normal modes of the system so when the solutions satisfy these, there are no scattered waves because those occur when non-normal modes are incident on the boundary.  I think it's another way of saying that the incident normal modes perfectly reflect into more normal modes, right?

Comment: Do you have a reference for your claim?